# Error: *(int **,int,int,int)' differs in levels of indirection from 'int ()', How can I fix it in my case?

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

I am trying to solve one of my homework problems that I was given. I am supposed to create a linked list and an array. The elements of the linked list is a struct of three ints and  a pointer to the next node. The elements of the array are structs of three ints as well.  A condition to put these specific struct into the linked list& array is when a given matrix fulfills: i+j equals to the element in the matrix in a specific iteration (where i and j are the iteration elements).

> ```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error 
> C2040 'createThreeArr': 'threesome *(int **,int,int,int)' differs in levels of indirection from 'int ()'
> ```

I got this error shown in the title of this post, can anyone help me understand why is this happening? What have I done wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct threesome
{
    int sum;
    int i;
    int j;
}threesome;

typedef struct list
{
    threesome data;
    struct list* next;
}list;


int createArrayAndList(int** arr, int rows, int cols, threesome** resArr, list** resList)
{
    int num;
    *resList = createThreeList(arr, rows, cols, &num);
    *resArr = createThreeArr(arr, rows, cols, num);
    return num;
}
threesome* createThreeArr(int** arr, int rows, int cols, int num) {
    threesome* new_array;
    int i, j, k;
    if (!num) return NULL;
    new_array = (threesome*)malloc(sizeof(threesome)*num);
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            if (arr[i][j] == i + j) {
                new_array[k].sum = arr[i][j];
                new_array[k].i = i;
                new_array[k].j = j;
                k++;
            }
    return new_array;
}
list* createThreeList(int** arr, int rows, int cols, int* length_list) {
    int i, j, count = 0;
    list *head = NULL, *temp1 = NULL, *temp2 = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == (i + j)) {
                temp2 = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
                temp2->data = createThree(i + j, i, j);
                temp2->next = NULL;
                if (!count) {
                    head = temp2;
                    temp1 = head;
                    count++;
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    temp1->next = temp2;
                    temp1 = temp1->next;
                    count++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    *length_list = count;
    return head;
}
threesome createThree(int num, int i, int j) {
    threesome strc;
    strc.sum = num;
    strc.i = i;
    strc.j = j;
    return strc;
}
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2040 'createThreeArr': 'threesome *(int **,int,int,int)' differs in levels of indirection from 'int ()'

Comment: Which line is that error on?

Comment: I've copied what you have in your comment into the question and formatted it a bit, but you may be able to do a better job (where's the line number, etc).  And please do this yourself in future — you can and should edit your question in response to most suggestions from the commentariat.

Comment: Thanks.  The error both in 31 and 47.

Comment: That's a... *different* type name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
int createArrayAndList(int** arr, int rows, int cols, threesome** resArr, list** resList)
{
    int num;
    *resList = createThreeList(arr, rows, cols, &num);
    *resArr = createThreeArr(arr, rows, cols, num);
    return num;
}
threesome* createThreeArr(int** arr, int rows, int cols, int num) {
    …
```

The call to `createThreeArr()` in `createArrayAndList()` implicitly declared `createThreeArr()` (and the call to `createThreeList()` does roughly the same):

```
extern int createThreeList();
extern int createThreeArr();
```

Those are functions returning an `int` with undefined (but not variadic) argument lists.

When the compiler comes across `threesome* createThreeArr(int** arr, int rows, int cols, int num) {` it thinks *That's not what you said before!* and generates the error message.

Declare or define your functions before calling them.  C99 requires it.  You get better error checking if you do that.  You can define a `static` function before it is used without pre-declaring it.

```
static threesome *createThreeArr(int **arr, int rows, int cols, int num);
static list *createThreeList(int **arr, int rows, int cols, int *length_list);
static threesome createThree(int num, int i, int j);
static int createArrayAndList(int** arr, int rows, int cols, threesome** resArr, list** resList);

static int createArrayAndList(int **arr, int rows, int cols, threesome **resArr, list **resList)
{
    …
}

…
```

If it was my code, all the functions except `main()` would be `static` (as above); if they were visible outside this source file, they'd be declared in a header and the header would be included here and wherever else the functions are used.

Comment: Thank you! can't believe that was the problem.

Comment: Get used to it — C++ requires functions to be declared before use, and so does modern C.  MSVS doesn't really support C99 or later, so it enforces the much more relaxed C90 rules where "if it looks like function but hasn't been seen before, it must be a function returning an `int` with indeterminate but non-variadic argument list".  Add options to get more warnings (`/W3` or `-W3` — maybe even `/W4` or `-W4` — if I remember correctly).  With GCC, I'd give you a list of options to use, but your error is from MSVC and not GCC.